# Python selection limiter

Tags: python, select, filter, boolean, limit

I am working on a project where I must ask the user to make a selection, I must limit their answers between 1-4 and have the program inform them when they have made a unacceptable selection. My issue comes when I try to modify the limiter to not crash when the user enters a empty space as a input.

No matter how I alter this code below, I receive a invalid syntax error. Any suggestions on how to fix this error? I do not know if it has anything to do with the boolean not, but that is the part of the code I added which causes the error. The original limiter was given to the entire class by the instructor.

```
def questionHairstyle():
    while True:
        hairchoice = ()
        questionsH = ("        1, for bald;" "\n" "        2, for crew-cut;"
        "\n" "        3, for curly;" "\n"   "        4, for wearing a hat;")
        print("Please enter a hairstyle:")
        print(questionsH)
        hairchoice = input("--> ", )
        print()
        if hairchoice[0] >= "1" and hairchoice[0] <= "4" 
        and not hairchoice[0] == " " and len(hairchoice) ==1:
        break
        print("Choice must be, between 1-4, not ", hairchoice + ".")
        print("Try again.")
```

The exact error message.

```
File "C:\Python34\Projects\sketch\sketch4.py", line 34
    if hairchoice[0] >= "1" and hairchoice[0] <= "4"
                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Have improvised code from @FunkySayu.

```
def questionHairstyle():
    while True:
        questionsH = ["    1, for bald;",
                "    2, for crew-cut;",
                "    3, for curly;",
                "    4, for wearing a hat"
                ]
        print("Please enter a hairstyle:")
        print("\n".join(questionsH))
        hairchoice = raw_input("-->")  #This will take even spaces
        print()
        if hairchoice in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
            break
        elif hairchoice == " ":     #This part checks for space as input from user
            print ("Space is encountered ")
            print("Choice must be, between 1-4, not ", hairchoice, ".")
            # This part of code can be extended for other user input also
        print("Try again.")


questionHairstyle()
```

output:

```
Please enter a hairstyle:
    1, for bald;
    2, for crew-cut;
    3, for curly;
    4, for wearing a hat
--> 
()
Space is encountered 
('Choice must be, between 1-4, not ', ' ', '.') #You can see the ' ' space is identified well in the output.
Try again.
Please enter a hairstyle:
    1, for bald;
    2, for crew-cut;
    3, for curly;
    4, for wearing a hat
-->
```

Comment: With a small modification (to remain within my instructors guidelines), this code fits my needs perfectly. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

**Final code at the end**

So first of all, the indentation. If you don't indent the `def` and the `while`, Python Interpreter will understand that the `while` statement is *outside* the function definition. But because nothing is defined in the function, Python raise an `IndentationError`, suspecting something is going wrong.

**EDIT** so in fact, you have another issue : your `if` statement is on 2 lines. Python doesn't understand this, so in case it's an error, he will raise a `SyntaxError`. To avoid it, just put a backslash `\` at the end of the first line of your if statement :

```
if hairchoice[0] >= "1" and hairchoice[0] <= "4" \
and not hairchoice[0] == " " and len(hairchoice) ==1:
```

After that, if you enter an empty result in the `input` function, you'll get a `SyntaxError`. As told in [What's the difference between raw_input() and input() in python3.x?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) Python2 will try to evaluate the input as Python code. If you want only a string, you can avoid this by using `raw_input`.

Last but not least, if you just press `Enter` key, you will get an `IndexError`. The reason is that you have an empty string `""` and you try to get the first index of this string. There's two way to deal with it :

The first one is to change the order of your conditions, putting `len(hairchoice) == 1` in the first position. The others wouldn't be evaluated if the first one is false.

The second one is to restrict the allowed strings. The if statement will looks like this : `if hairchoice in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:`

```
def questionHairstyle():
    while True:
        hairchoice = ()
        questionsH = ("        1, for bald;" "\n" "        2, for crew-cut;"
        "\n" "        3, for curly;" "\n"   "        4, for wearing a hat;")
        print("Please enter a hairstyle:")
        print(questionsH)
        hairchoice = raw_input("--> ")
        print()
        if hairchoice in ["1", "2", "3", "4"]:
            break
        print("Choice must be, between 1-4, not ", hairchoice, ".")
        print("Try again.")
```

Comment: Indentation wasn't an issue, that came about from pasting the code into this site. raw_input didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Damn i understand... In fact, it's because your condition is not in the same line. Add an \ at the end of the first line

Comment: Ran into too many secondary problems with adjusting the code to use the original limiter. I am using the one you created as modified by Manjunath N. 

Thank you for the help you've both provided.